# NIS client doesn't see group names

Tags: authentication, nis, nsswitch.conf, yp

I have added a user to libvirt (id = 504) group on NIS server. On the client when I do    `group <user>`, I get `<user> groups: cannot find name for group ID 504` What should I do to get my clients to display group names correctly ?

There are no id conflicts between local machine and NIS server
nscd is not running. My /etc/nsswitch.conf looks like this:

```
passwd:     compat nis
shadow:     compat nis
group:      compat nis
```

Appreciate any help in debugging this.

Comment: Do you mean "groups" instead of group? What do you get with "getent group libvirt" and "getent group 504"? Please post the results of "grep 504 /etc/group" from your NIS master and the problem box.